# Scope client people picker to multiple user groups

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I use the client people picker.

Currently, it picks all users in the site. Can I scope it to several SharePoint  user groups (*4 target SP groups within the site*), so that only the SharePoint  users in those 4 groups are picked from the client people picker?